# Play a video from remote computer using NGINX-RTMP

Tags: nginx, jwplayer

I am trying to stream a video  using nginx-rtmp with rtmp protocol.
I created a index.html and  embedded on it JWPlayer with the rtmp url.
On localhost, I can play the video from the browser but from another computer in same local network when I tried same thing ( open the index.html in the browser the url is http://172.16.40.162:8080 ) I get an error message.
But when I try  with vlc (the rtmp url : rtmp://172.16.40.162/vod/test) it worked.
Here the code of index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>VoD Example</title>
        <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/s7iNvOAyEeSMdQ4AfQhyIQ.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id='videotest'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('videotest').setup({
        file: 'rtmp://localhost/vod/test',
        width: '50%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the nginx.conf

```
    #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        # rtmp stat
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }
        location /stat.xsl {
            # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
            root /usr/local/nginx/html;
        }

        # rtmp control
        location /control {
            rtmp_control all;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
    notify_method get;
    chunk_size 8192;

        application vod {
        allow play all;
        wait_video on;
            play /var/www/Videos;
        push rtmp://localhost/vod/test;
        }
    }
}
```

I get these messages on :

**acces.log**

```
    172.16.40.148 - - [16/Apr/2015:13:08:33 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"
172.16.40.148 [16/Apr/2015:13:19:29 +0100] PLAY "vod" "test" "" - 382 3660906 "" "LNX 9,0,124,2" (1m 58s)
127.0.0.1 [16/Apr/2015:13:51:47 +0100] PLAY "vod" "test" "" - 483 3669724 "http://172.16.40.162:8080/" "LNX 11,2,202,457" (1m 50s)
```

**error.log**

```
2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3771#0: using the "epoll" event method
    2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3771#0: nginx/1.5.0
    2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3771#0: built by gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) 
    2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3771#0: OS: Linux 2.6.32-504.12.2.el6.x86_64
    2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3771#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:4096
    2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3772#0: start worker processes
    2015/04/16 13:07:06 [notice] 3772#0: start worker process 3773
    2015/04/16 13:08:41 [info] 3773#0: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 172.16.40.148, server: 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Information about the video I use (I executed ffmpeg -i test.flv)

```
    Input #0, flv, from 'test.flv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf56.30.100
  Duration: 00:01:50.03, start: 0.060000, bitrate: 270 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s
```

Comment: Do you have a way to provide an example of this that can be tested either online or locally?

Comment: I provided the index.html code and nginx.conf that I used also I installed nginx 1.5.0 with rtmp module. I use all this in CentOS release 6.6 (Final).   The script of JWPlayer was generated from https://account.jwplayer.com/#/publish/select/internet. And From there I could play the video when I put rtmp://localhost/vod/test in Media File filed and click on publish button.

Comment: Yes, I am wondering if there is a way for me to test your set up though. The JW Player part of the code looks fine.

Comment: Like I said from Localhost, it worked fine when I used the browser and it worked fine from a remote computer (in same LAN), when I use vlc (with rtmp url) , but I got an erro (Error loading stream: Coul not connect to server) when I tried from browser.

Comment: Is there a way I can connect from my remote machine to test it? Any firewall settings?

Comment: No, I couldn't disable the firewall or made an exception.

Comment: It's like sending a photo of your car to your mechanic, and asking him to figure out why it won't start. Good luck, esprittn.

Comment: I need a way to test this myself...

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer runs on the client machine and the requests are made from the client. You can't use `localhost` on the JWPlayer embed unless you really want to play a stream available on the client computer.

Comment: I know that. I wanted to connect to their machine remotely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `index.html` replace `file: 'rtmp://localhost/vod/test'` with `file: 'rtmp://172.16.40.162/vod/test'`.

The JWPlayer Flash will request that URL **from the client machine**. Using `localhost` will obviously not work since it looks for the stream on the same computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just one more think. Could you please help me to configure nginx-rtmp for live streaming on hls.

Comment: Sure. Can you post a new question with the HLS issues?